# Как правильно расположить вью на экране

Tags: java, android

Есть у меня экран в ктором скролл вью, в этом скрол вью другие вьюхи

Так вот проблема в том, что почти на всех экранах все смотриться хорошо

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

а вот на экране `Samsung S8` элементы в скролвью занимают место сверху вниз и получается что остается много пустого места внизу.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

На этом скриншоте видно, что осталось очень много лишнего места.

Я пробовал добавить еще одну дерикторию

`res/layout-xlarge/my_layout.xml`

согласно этому ответу на стаке

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20763322/android-supporting-multiple-resolution-with-multiple-layout-folder

но лайоут в этой папке влияет на все экраны с `extra large screen size`, что тоже не подходит так как допустим `Samsung S5` тоже берет лайоут из этой папки хотя его экран по размеру меньше

Как правильно сделать?

Если что то забыл спрашивайте

Comment: Попробуйте папку с модификатором по высоте экрана. Что-то типа `layout-h800dp` - то есть для телефонов с высотой минимум 800dp.

Comment: @eugeneek не, не работает

Comment: А сколько dp по высоте на S8? Вы подставили нужное значение вместо 800?

Comment: @eugeneek да я поставил 800 , а нужно было 650(это я определил методом научного тыка) и в итоге я подумал, чтоб не плодить лайоуты то лучше это сделать в `dimens` создал папку `values-h650dp` и положил туда файл со значением для вью `Space` в общем вроде получилось то что нужно. Но идея ваша, так что если хотите сделайте в виде ответа я апрувну

Comment: Уступаю это право вам)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В итоге создал папку с файлом ресурсов по высоте экрана для самсунг с8+

Получилось вот так `values-h650dp/dimens.xml`

В этот файл добавил значение

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
<!--search view space-->
<dimen name="search_view_space">20dp</dimen>

</resources>
```

а в файле для остальных экранов `values/dimens.xml` сделал так

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
<!--search view space-->
<dimen name="search_view_space">0dp</dimen>

</resources>
```

И в разметку добавил там где нужно

```
<android.support.v4.widget.Space
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/search_view_space"/>
```

Вот и получилось, что для всех экранов визуально ничего не меняется а для экранов с размером больше чем 650dp по высоте каждый `Space` получает значение 20dp